# How to embed an element in a page object widget

Tags: pageobjects, page-object-gem

I have the following widget...

```
class MdRadioButton < PageObject::Elements::RadioButton
  extend PageObject::Accessors
  label :title, :class => "control-label"
  def select
    self.click
  end
  def selected?
    self.class_name.include? "md-checked"
  end
end
PageObject.register_widget :md_radio_button , MdRadioButton, :element
```

Then I try to access the title like this...

```
md_radio_buttons(:rdio, :class => "my-radio")
...
rdio_elements.each do |option|
  if option.title == alert_group
    option.select
  end
end
```

But when I `option.title` I get...

> undefined method `platform' for #<Watir::HTMLElement:0x162e57d8\>

`option.select` works fine

**Update**

I tried this...

```
class MdRadioButton < PageObject::Elements::RadioButton
  extend PageObject::Accessors
  include PageObject
```

Now the `.title` works but `.select` does not.

> wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the accessor methods to work within a widget, they need to access the platform. This can be done by adding an `attr_reader`:

```
class MdRadioButton < PageObject::Elements::RadioButton
  extend PageObject::Accessors
  attr_reader :platform

  label :title, :class => "control-label"
  def select
    self.click
  end
  def selected?
    self.class_name.include? "md-checked"
  end
end
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something like that, I just didn't know where platform was located. Thank you I will test it out!